# JPA Specification criteria can't access attribute

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin

I'm trying to access the property `name` in the class `Destination`. But I'm doing something wrong.

Destination.name is wrong, I tried "destination" and many other things but all I tried didn't work.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong here?

Code:

```
class FlightEntity(uuid: UUID? = null,
                  .....
                  @ManyToOne(optional = false) val destination: Destination,
                  .... : BaseEntity(uuid)


class Destination(uuid: UUID? = null,
                 @Column(nullable = false) val name: String) : 
BaseEntity(uuid)          

fun hasDesName(destinationName: String): Specification<FlightEntity> {
    return Specification { root, _, builder ->
        builder.equal(root.get<FlightEntity>("destination.name"), 
destinationName)
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try `root.get<FlightEntity>("destination").get("name")`. Not entirely sure if anything else is needed syntax-wise in Kotlin; I generally only use JPA in Java

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Thanks! get<Destination>("name") worked for me.